# Program prints if statement requiring specific input even though another input is done

Tags: java

I'm writing a program for class on inflation over time. The user has to input the price of the item, number of years over which it inflates, and inflation rate. I have all of the variables defined, and some if statements for when the user inputs something less than 0 so it will create an error message. However no matter what I put in, it keeps coming out as the first input error message: "The current price must be at least 0!". I'm pretty new to coding and this is my first class so I'm still not super up to speed on everything. Any help is appreciated, thank you! I'll put my code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class inflation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int years, num=1;
    double price, percent;
    
    System.out.print("Enter the current price of the item: $");
    price = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter the number of years: ");
    years = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the inflation rate as a percentage: ");
    percent = input.nextDouble();
    
    percent = percent/100;
    
    if (price<0); {
        System.out.println("The current price must be at least 0!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    
    if (years<0); {
        System.out.println("The number of years must be at least 0!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    
    if (percent<0);{
        System.out.println("The inflation rate must be at least 0");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    
    while (num<=years) {
        price = price*(1+percent);
        num = num+1;    
    }
    
    if ((years==0) || (price==0) || (percent ==0)) {
        System.out.printf("After %d years, the price will be $%.2f%n", years, price);
    }
    
    if (years==1) {
        System.out.printf("After %d year, the price will be $%.2f%n", years, price);
    }
    
    if (years==2) {
        System.out.printf("After %d years, the price will be $%.2f%n", years, price);
    }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: *"The current price must be at least 0!"*  - yeah but which one?

Comment: sorry about that! That was from me tinkering around with it, it's the first one, I changed the code to reflect that.

Comment: `if (price<0);` - get rid of `;`  Check your other code as well

Comment: I removed it and it stopped printing the if statement, but now it won't print the results, is that because of the system exits?

Comment: what is the value of `years` ?

Answer (score 0):

We shouldn't use **;** after if statement.

Currently you're using like below.

```
if (price<0); {
        System.out.println("The current price must be at least 0!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Try to use below snippet in your code. It might help you.

```
if (price<=0) {
        System.out.println("The current price must be at least 0! price");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```